# jQuery UI Date Picker issue on IE9 and below. Shows wrong date in UTC +2 time zones

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

- Use **IE9** or below.
- Change the time zone of the computer to UTC+2 -Amman.
- Navigate to https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
- Click in the textbox to reveal date picker control.
- Use the arrows to go to Apr/2016.
- You can see the day of 01/Apr/2016 as **Thursday** which is **INCORRECT**.
- Use **IE10** or above, shows the day of 01/Apr/2016 as **Friday** which
  is **CORRECT**.

Any fix available for this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery date picker control relies on JS Date function to build the calendar. Apparently, JS date function reports wrong info in IE9 and below.

For example:
**new Date(2016,3,1)**
IE9 and below prints Thu Mar 31 23:00:00 UTC+0200 2016 - **INCORRECT**
IE10 and above prints Fri Apr 1 01:00:00 UTC+0300 2016[date] Fri Apr 1 01:00:00 UTC+0300 2016 - **CORRECT**

**Possible Fix:**
Edit the jQueryUI JS file and update the function _getFirstDayOfMonth as below.

```
_getFirstDayOfMonth: function (year, month) {
            // This code is needed as IE9 and below reports the wrong date value for UTC+2 timezones
            if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 9.0") > -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 8.0") > -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") > -1)
                return new Date( year, month, 1,23 ).getDay();
            else
                return new Date( year, month, 1 ).getDay();
        }
```